# Render to /auth/... page

Tags: node.js

Here is my contact page:
[image]

After user successfully submitting letter it renders to contact page with verification message:
[image]

Now problem is that after render my html changes to: [image]

Everything would be alright, but at this point I don't know how to check if user is logged in, should I create something familiar to this below?

[image]

I cant find solution, should I provide more information about this problem?

Comment: why you don't use session?

Comment: I use cookie authentication

Comment: Is there any way to remove /auth/ in my link? I don't know any serious website has link like that

Comment: yes, You can create a middleware that can check if the user is logged in or not. and use this in any route you want. in order to delete auth from your route you should go to the place that you import these routes and delete auth. I suggest you to right like this :
router.get("/contact", isAuth, contactController);

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I solved my problem by putting all my router.post and router.get to one place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).